# Pulling php data, using split to separate the commas in the string, and posting the data in a div using ajax to refresh every 3 seconds

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, get, split

I'm trying to pull a php string such as '10,58,72,15,4,723,' and use split() to separate the commas into arrays.  I then want to put the arrays into different divs and refresh the data every 3 seconds.  Here is my code but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var hope = $.get('withdacommas.php');
   var mystr = hope.split(',');
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() 
 { $('#quote p').fadeOut("fast").load(mystr[0]).fadeIn("fast"); }, 3000);  
});
```

Could someone explain where I went wrong and if there is a better way to do this? I think I've messed up with the **load(array[0])** part but I'm not sure how.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer below (invalid use of an ajax call) is correct. However, I just wanted to note that you shouldn't use 'array' as a variable name... it's a reserved javascript keyword and can lead to some unpleasant issues in some browsers: http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

Comment: @Ben Thank you. I've change 'array' to 'mystr'.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in your JQuery AJAX

The method get() does not return a value, rather it runs a function once the return value is received from the php file.

```
$.get({
   url: 'someurl',
   success: function(response) {
      // handle response data here
   }
});
```

More info here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Thank you. I'm guessing that load() will work instead but can you explain how I can then incorporate that into the refreshId variable so that the array will display correctly in the div? Somehow I think I've made this more complicated then it has to be.

Comment: @user1112733 load will load an elements contents with the entire returned response. Since you have to parse the returned response and put different parts into different elements, get() would be your best bet. After you break up the data, you would cycle through a JQuery selector full of elements and the array with the returned data at the same time, replacing each elements content with the corresponding array item or whatever it is that you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was closer than I thought!

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
 setInterval(function() {
 $.get('withdacommas.php', function(data) {
  var data = data.split(",");
  $('#result').html(data[2]); }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

That did it!